# Should NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop.dll be in the GAC to use it as a wizard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, project-template

I am creating a project template.  I would like to have it auto install unity and prism via NuGet.

[I read here how to do that](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates).  I setup my vstemplate file like that page indicates:

```
 <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <packages>
        <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.0" />
        <package id="Prism" version="4.1.0.0" />
        <package id="Prism.UnityExtensions" version="4.1.0.0" />
        <package id="Unity" version="2.1.505.0" />
    </packages>
  </WizardData>
```

It seems to be setup right, but it does not work.  When I try to use my template I get this error message:

> Could not add all required packages to the project. The following packages failed to install from 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectTemplatesCache\MyTemplate.zip'

I did some looking, and for a Wizard to work, it needs to be installed in the GAC.  I ran this command:

> gacutil.exe /l NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop

And it returned:

> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>
> Number of items = 0

So it seems it is not in the GAC.  The question is: **How does this work for everyone else then?  If it needs to be in the GAC, then why is it not there automatically?**

If not, then why does it not work (I am fairly sure it needs to be in the GAC though).

Note: I did find that dll here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager\1.6.21215.9133

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had missed this important part of the docs:

> The template needs to specify where to find the package nupkg files. Currently two package repositories are supported:
>
> > Packages embedded inside of a VSIX package.
> >        Packages embedded inside of the project/item template itself.

So, there is no way to get packages from the actual NuGet Repository.

Answer (score -1):

Answer for this Question:

Open Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions and Updates > choose Online link and then right side search bar type  NuGet Package Manager. Then Download and Install. Solves your problem